# Issue with all WCF Callback clients faulting when one faults

Tags: c#, wcf, callback

I'm trying to figure out why when you have multiple callback clients connected using the well-known publish-subscribe pattern when one faults or when one disconnects without unsubscribing all the clients states are set to Closed then Faulted.

```
   [ServiceContract(SessionMode = SessionMode.Required, CallbackContract = typeof(ICallback))]
   public interface IPubSubService
   {
      [OperationContract(IsOneWay = false, IsInitiating = true)]
      void Subscribe();

      [OperationContract(IsOneWay = false, IsInitiating = true)]
      void UnSubscribe();

      [OperationContract(IsOneWay = false)]
      void BroadcastMessage(string message);
   }


   [ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.PerSession)]
   public class PubSubService : IPubSubService
   {
      private ICallback _callbackClient;
      public static event Action<string> _action;

      public void Subscribe()
      {
         _callbackClient = OperationContext.Current.GetCallbackChannel<ICallback>();
         _action += ActionInvoked;
      }

      public void UnSubscribe()
      {
         _action -= ActionInvoked;
      }

      public void BroadcastMessage(string message)
      {
         _action.Invoke(message);
      }

      public void ActionInvoked(string message)
      {
         _callbackClient.SendMessage(message);
      }
   }

   public interface ICallback
   {
      [OperationContract(IsOneWay = true)]
      void SendMessage(string message);
   }


// The Publisher that doesn't subscribe only sends the message
[CallbackBehaviorAttribute(UseSynchronizationContext = false)]
   public partial class Form1 : Form, ICallback
   {
      public Form1()
      {
         InitializeComponent();
      }

      private ServiceClient _proxy;

      private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
      {
         try
         {
            _proxy = new ServiceClient(new InstanceContext(this));
            _proxy.BroadcastMessage(textBox1.Text);
         }
         catch (Exception exception)
         {
            Console.WriteLine(exception);
         }
      }


      public void SendMessage(string message)
      {

      }
   }

   public static class ControlExtensions
   {
      public static void Invoke(this Control Control, Action Action)
      {
         Control.Invoke(Action);
      }
   }

   public class ServiceClient : DuplexClientBase<IPubSubService>, IPubSubService
   {
      public ServiceClient(InstanceContext callbackInstance)
         : base(callbackInstance)
      { }

      public void Subscribe()
      {
         Channel.Subscribe();
      }

      public void UnSubscribe()
      {
         Channel.UnSubscribe();
      }

      public void BroadcastMessage(string message)
      {
         Channel.BroadcastMessage(message);
      }
   }

// The Subscriber
[CallbackBehaviorAttribute(UseSynchronizationContext = false)]
   public partial class Form1 : Form, ICallback
   {
      public Form1()
      {
         InitializeComponent();
      }

      private ServiceClient _proxy;

      private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
      {
         _proxy = new ServiceClient(new InstanceContext(this));
         _proxy.Subscribe();
         this.Invoke(() => textBox1.AppendText("Subscribed..."));

      }

      public void SendMessage(string message)
      {
         this.Invoke(() => textBox1.AppendText(message + "\r\n"));
      }

      private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
      {
         if (_proxy != null && _proxy.State == CommunicationState.Opened)
         {
            _proxy.UnSubscribe();
         }
      }

      private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
      {
         Thread.Sleep(new TimeSpan(0, 1, 0));
      }
   }

   public static class ControlExtensions
   {
      public static void Invoke(this Control Control, Action Action)
      {
         Control.Invoke(Action);
      }
   }

   public class ServiceClient : DuplexClientBase<IPubSubService>, IPubSubService
   {
      public ServiceClient(InstanceContext callbackInstance) : base(callbackInstance)
      { }

      public void Subscribe()
      {
         Channel.Subscribe();
      }

      public void UnSubscribe()
      {
         Channel.UnSubscribe();
      }

      public void BroadcastMessage(string message)
      {
         Channel.BroadcastMessage(message);
      }
   }


// config for both clients publisher and subscriber

<configuration>
  <system.windows.forms jitDebugging="true" />
  <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <netTcpBinding>
        <binding name="netTCPBinding">
          <reliableSession ordered="true" inactivityTimeout="00:10:00" enabled="true"/>
          <security mode="None">
          </security>
        </binding>
      </netTcpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
      <endpoint
        address="net.tcp://localhost:8008/PubSubService"
        binding="netTcpBinding"
        bindingConfiguration="netTCPBinding"
        contract="ServiceLibrary.IPubSubService"
        name="netTCPBinding">
        <identity>
          <dns value="localhost"/>
        </identity>
      </endpoint>
    </client>
  </system.serviceModel>
  <startup>
  </startup>
</configuration>

// config for Service

<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>  
  <system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service name="ServiceLibrary.PubSubService">
        <endpoint address="net.tcp://localhost:8008/PubSubService"
                  binding="netTcpBinding"
                  bindingConfiguration="netTCPBinding"
                  contract="ServiceLibrary.IPubSubService"/>
      </service>
    </services>
    <bindings>
      <netTcpBinding>
        <binding name="netTCPBinding" closeTimeout="00:00:10" openTimeout="00:00:10" receiveTimeout="00:00:10" sendTimeout="00:00:10" transactionFlow="false" transferMode="Buffered" maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxBufferSize="65536" maxConnections="1000" maxReceivedMessageSize="65536">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="16384" maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384"/>
          <reliableSession ordered="true" inactivityTimeout="00:10:00" enabled="true"/>
          <security mode="None">
          </security>
        </binding>
      </netTcpBinding>      
    </bindings>
  </system.serviceModel>  
<startup><supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.0"/></startup></configuration>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Isn't it simply a case of the disconnected client causes the event raising to throw an exception when processing its invocation list and therefore all remaining clients don;t get invoked - you could process the invocation list manually something like this

```
        List<Action<string>> targets = _action.GetInvocationList().Cast<Action<string>>().ToList();

        foreach(var target in targets)
        {
           try
           {
               target(message);
           }
           catch(CommunicationException)
           {
               _action -= target;
           }
        }
```

**Edit (After looking at the code)**

You are using NetTcpBinding which is inherently [sessionful](http://www.dotnetconsult.co.uk/weblog2/PermaLink,guid,af6e6325-2e30-42e3-acb9-57e1363fa51e.aspx). That session will be torn down (disconnected) in one of two situations - when the client closes their proxy or *when the services receiveTimeout is exceeded between requests*.

In your PubSubService host you had the receive timeout (which affects the subscribers sessions) set to 5 seconds, the same as the sendTimeout (which affects the time you'll wait before deciding the subscriber is dead when you are broadcasting). So by the time you realise the subscriber is dead, all of the other subscribers have timed out their sessions

Increase your receiveTimeout in the PubSubService host to the amount of time you want the subscriptions to be valid and it will work fine

Comment: still the same result, if one faults or closes, they all lose connection.

Comment: OK can we get a bit more info about your setup? What bindings are you using? what does the client code look like? How are you hosting the service?

Comment: sure, I'll edit my original question and add the rest of the code and app.config settings.

Comment: In another app I'm trying I am using the pubsub pattern but setting the service to be singleton in the attributes, and then adding subscribed clients to a List<ICallback>.  When I try the same thing (close a subscribed client without unsubscribing) I get the same result, but in addition to that if I for say pause the client while the service is looping through the List and trying to call it's callback then the service get's an exception and that exception is not caught even though it's in a Try Catch, the error I get is " the server did not provide a meaningful response..."

Comment: actually Mark, can you zip this up and post it somewhere and I'll  to debug it and work out what's wrong. I think you have a thread deadlock that is stopping responses from happening resulting in your error

Comment: will do, let me clean it up and I'll put it in my dropbox account, give me about 15 minutes. Thanks.

Comment: Hi Mark, I've had a look at the code and the issue comes down to a combination of your binding and timeouts I'll amend my answer